# Memory maxed out after a fresh install of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 for a client (Xen Virtulazation) and there is nothing installed yet, and the ram is at 100% non stop

For some reason there are many rsyslogd's running... not sure why
and I am completely stumped

[image]

Comment: Also mention if you read and understood [Linux ate all my RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). Basically memory being used is GOOD. Otherwise you might as well put it in a desk drawer.

Comment: Ok, there is the answer I needed! Newbie mistake. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Your memory use is 98MB out of 1451 available, or ~7%. What makes you think 100% is in use? As for the multiple `rsyslogd` entries, they are the different threads within the same process.

Comment: In useful OS environments, unused memory is wasted memory. All that buffering that can be done if it's not being used for program and OS is a good thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [memory usage linux in top is not correct](http://superuser.com/questions/271390/memory-usage-linux-in-top-is-not-correct)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine there!
Your actual memory usage are green bars.
You can learn more about `htop` by pressing `?` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your system is *not* running out of memory. Instead, otherwise unused memory is being used to speed up access to data on disk. This [cached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) data is automatically freed up for use by applications as needed.

- This is a common source of confusion for Linux newcomers especially when they look at `free` output. For more information, see **["Linux ate my RAM!"](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)**
- On systems running Windows 8 or later, this memory is reported as "standby" in Task Manager:

  > Memory that contains cached data and code that is not actively in use

  The yellow portion of the bar in `htop` on your Ubuntu system is essentially what Windows would refer to as "standby" memory.